# VBA Management tool?

Tags: vba, ms-project

I use MS Project Professional 2013, and I need to find a tool for code management for VBA. I would like this tool to be able to import and export code from/to MSP and the ability to integration with TFS. Can you recommend something to me?

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to do the same thing, but in the end it's easier to just migrate to full VB.net and build your code as an add-in using the full power of Visual Studio. You get complete dev and test tools, plus integration with TFS, and a much better IDE to work with. The learning curve for the VB stuff is minimal (same language syntax, same Project Object Model), but there is a little getting used to Visual Studio.

There are some (rather complicated) solutions out there, but if you are ready for managed code you may as well take the leap.